# How to use Simple Cursor Adapter with Recycler View?

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a SQL Database and the Recycler View. I am just having trouble giving the Recycler View the data from the database. I have done some reading and from what I understand I need to implement a SimpleCursorAdapter for the recycler view. I have looked some guides up but have been unsuccessful. Thanks!

Here is the Recycler View Java Code:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<MainInfo> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public RVAdapter (Context context, List<MainInfo> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Title, Body;

         MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Row_Header);
            Body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Row_Footer);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Database java code

```
    public class ManagerDatabaseAdapter{

    ManagerHelper helper;

    public ManagerDatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        helper = new ManagerHelper(context);
    }

    public long inserData(String name, String code) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ManagerHelper.NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(ManagerHelper.CODE,code);
        long id = db.insert(ManagerHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return id;
    }

    public String getAllData () {
        String[] columns = {ManagerHelper.UID,ManagerHelper.NAME,ManagerHelper.CODE};
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ManagerHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int cid = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String code = cursor.getString(2);
            buffer.append(cid+" "+name+" "+code+"/n");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public String getData(String name) {
        String[] columns = {ManagerHelper.NAME,ManagerHelper.CODE};
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ManagerHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, ManagerHelper.NAME+" = '"+name+"'", null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(ManagerHelper.NAME);
            int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(ManagerHelper.CODE);
            String placename = cursor.getString(index1);
            String code = cursor.getString(2);
            buffer.append(name+" "+code+"/n");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public int updatePlace(String oldName, String newName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ManagerHelper.NAME, newName);
        String[] whereArgs= {oldName};
        int count = db.update(ManagerHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ManagerHelper.NAME+" =?", whereArgs);
        return count;
    }

    public long deleteRow(String delete) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] whereArgs = {delete};
        long id = db.delete(ManagerHelper.TABLE_NAME, ManagerHelper.NAME +  " =?", whereArgs);
        return id;
    }

static class ManagerHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager.LOCATION";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Main_Data";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "DATA";
    private static final int VERSION = 2;
    private static final String UID = "_id";
    private static final String NAME = "Codes";
    private static final String CODE = "Code";
    private static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+CODE+" VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP_TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context;

    public ManagerHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        //Message.message(context,"Constructor Called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,LocationAdder.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,true);
        context.startActivity(intent);

        try {
            MainActivity.firstRun();
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            //Message.message(context,"onCreate called");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //Message.message(context,""+e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                //Message.message(context,"onUpgrade called");
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            }catch (SQLException e){
                //Message.message(context,""+e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My approach would be using `Loader` to load data into a `List`, then just implement a typical `RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>` to show data from the `List`

Comment: try [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter

Comment: If you are running a query with a CursorLoader and you want RecyclerView instead of ListView.

You can try my CursorRecyclerViewAdapter: https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

Comment: @ExceptionLover I saw that and tried to use it, but I was not sure what to do in the myListItem fromCursorAdapter? Sorry, that is probably a noob question. Thanks.